# MockGoogleCredential in C#

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I'd like to mock a `GoogleCredential` class. I found a lot of results for Java. But nothing for C#. Is there a special Nuget package? Or an alternative?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're intending to *do* with the credential? Do you really need a mock, or are you just trying to provide "a credential" elsewhere? (Do you definitely need a full `GoogleCredential` rather than an `ICredential`? Or would `GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken` be enough, perhaps?) If you can give more details of what you're trying to achieve, we're more likely to be able to help.

Comment: Google is using OAUTH2 authentication which is a two step authentication using HTTP Request/Response.  Step one is to get a token/cookie. Step 2 is to use the token in the query.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-8.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Comment: We use a library created in our company where one method requires a GoogleCredential. I'd like to mock this interface. But I can't test anything without a google credential

Comment: "But I can't test anything without a google credential" - but that doesn't mean you need a mock. That's why I suggested using `GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken` as a simple way of creating *a* `GoogleCredential`. I wouldn't use mocking unless you need specific interaction testing.

Comment: The hint with ICredential solved my problem. Thanks